# Replacing variables on a string

Tags: combinatorics

In a long string of 100 alphabets, I have 2 possible options at 20 places and 3 possible options at 5 places. How many total combinations are possible?

It appears to me that it is 
$num of variables ^ {no of places}$ for each kind

So for 2 variables and 20 places, there will be $2^{20}$ (1048576) possible strings and for 3 variables and 5 places, there will be $3^5$ (243) possible strings.

So the total string combinations = $1048576 \times 243 = 254803968$

Is this correct?

Comment: I don't understand the bit about the $100$ alphabets.  Does that have anything to do with the problem?

Comment: The variables are replaced at specific places on the 100 alphabet string. At 20 places there are 2 options and at 5 places there are 3 options. The rest of the string remains the same in all the combinations.

Comment: Well, if you have $20$ binary choices to make and $5$ trinary choices then the number of combinations is indeed $2^{20}\times 3^5$.